# C# - How to retrieve a connectionString from an App.config, Encrypting config sections

Tags: c#, encryption, configuration, app-config

I have a configuration file that looks super simple like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="SQLServerConnectionString" connectionString="connection1"/>
   <add name ="OracleServerConnectionString" connectionString="connection2"/>
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

It couldn't get any easier than that. I am trying to encrypt the "connectionStrings" section. I've tried and tried to do this by following many online turotrials but have not been able to get it to work. I think I have possibly found the root of my issue. Basically when I do this:

```
string conectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

I **am** able to get the expected result of "connection1".

However, when I do this:

```
var appconfigDir = @"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyProject\App.config";

System.Configuration.Configuration config = 
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(appconfigDir);

ConnectionStringsSection section = 
config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;

var connectionString = section.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerConnectionString"];
```

I keep getting null! Can someone help me with this? I Can't understand why I am unable to get my connection string using the second method.

I am trying to encrypt my "App.config" by doing the following

```
section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
```

This works, but when I decrypt:

```
section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
```

I am unable to get my origional connection strings. I basically just get a blank "connectionString" section.

Comment: appconfigDir should be pointing to the .exe

Comment: So are you saying it shuold point to the actual `.exe` and not the `exe.config`? I had it pointing to the `exe.config` in my case. I wrote App.config but I meant to say exe.config, sorry.

Comment: You were right! Please post this as an answer, thank you!!!!

Comment: Is this on a server app or a desktop app? Because it is nearly pointless to encrypt configuration on a desktop app. If the app can decrypt then the user can too.

Comment: It is a desktop app running on a secure server on a secure network. Normally I wuold agree with what you are saying, sure if someone gets this app and runs it (which they shuoldn't as this is one off custom software) then they "could" run the app and decryp the connection strings. BUT since I am encrypting using a machine key even if they get the source, they would have to be on this exact machine to decrypt the connection strings.